# Why does my Update to a sub document remove the array nature of sub document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this

```
{
 "ClockID" : "fd51b6e0-5b81-49ab-8424-71fd768281b2",
 "ClockName" : "AAA-TEST123-002",
 "FilesList" : [{
                 "FileName" : "AAA-TEST123-002.mpg",
                 "FileLocationHistory" :    [{
                                               "FullPath" : "192.168.32.166/Ingestion",
                                               "AllowDeleteOnCancel" : false,
                                               "_id" : "565b7343-9dc5-4916-a788-0f392fce2502"
                                    }],
                  "_id" : "15b54499-a0be-4278-82ed-58c82c13bd40",
               }],
 "_id" : ObjectId("510164d0a63cfa2250fd6d19"),
 "_t" : "ClockRecord"
```

When I update the FileLocationHistory array document with this:

```
    public void UpdateClockFilesLocationRecord(string collectionName, ClockFileLocationHistoryRecord clockFileLocationHistory, BsonObjectId clockDocumentID, string clockFileDocumentID)
    {
        var mongoCollection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<ClockRecord>("Clocks");
        var update = Update.Set("FilesList.$.FileLocationHistory", BsonDocumentWrapper.Create<ClockFileLocationHistoryRecord>(clockFileLocationHistory));
        var modeResult = mongoCollection.Update(
             Query.And(
                Query.EQ("_id", clockDocumentID),
                Query.EQ("FilesList._id", clockFileDocumentID)
                ), 
              update, UpdateFlags.Upsert
              );
    }
```

the update goes through but the document is no longer an array:

```
{
 "ClockID" : "fd51b6e0-5b81-49ab-8424-71fd768281b2",
 "ClockName" : "AAA-TEST123-002",
 "FilesList" : [{
                 "FileName" : "AAA-TEST123-002.mpg",
                 "FileLocationHistory" :    {
                                               "FullPath" : "192.168.32.166/Ingestion",
                                               "AllowDeleteOnCancel" : false,
                                               "_id" : "565b7343-9dc5-4916-a788-0f392fce2502"
                                    },
                  "_id" : "15b54499-a0be-4278-82ed-58c82c13bd40",
               }],
 "_id" : ObjectId("510164d0a63cfa2250fd6d19"),
 "_t" : "ClockRecord"
```

Which means the document tries to de-serialise as an object that the driver does not recognise.

What is wrong with my update code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var update = Update.Set("FilesList.$.FileLocationHistory", BsonDocumentWrapper.Create<ClockFileLocationHistoryRecord>(clockFileLocationHistory));
```

You could use push:

```
var update = MongoUpdate.Push("FilesList.$.FileLocationHistory", BsonDocumentWrapper.Create<ClockFileLocationHistoryRecord>(clockFileLocationHistory));
```

... to add to the array

Comment: Thanks that works.  Unfortunately to be an update I need to pull the original document and I have tried all manner of ways to achieve this without success.

Comment: For example:   var updatePull = Update.Pull("FilesList.$.FileLocationHistory",BsonDocumentWrapper.Create(Query.EQ("FileLocationHistory._id",clockFileLocationHistoryRecord._id)));

            var modeResultPull = mongoCollection.Update(
             Query.And(
                Query.EQ("_id", clockDocumentID),
                Query.EQ("FilesList._id", clockFileDocumentID)
                ),
                updatePull, UpdateFlags.Upsert
              );

Comment: I forgot to say re your push code I used Update.Push and not MongoUpdate.Push